# Select a table on a certain page Word interop

Tags: c#

I'm trying to select a table on a certain page on a word document. However my code is selecting tables from the whole document.

I'm trying to do it like this and I'm not sure why it won't do it.

```
  word.Pages pages = doc.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.Pages;
            foreach (word.Table p in pages[4].Application.ActiveDocument.Tables)
            {
                p.Select();

            }
```

Comment: Just cause you start at a page when referencing back to `Application` doesn't mean you get a special application object for your current page. It's still the same application object that you would get from any other page.

Comment: I am not familiar with the office API, but your problem seems to make sense. You are accessing page index number 4 (page 5), and on it, referencing its Application object reference, its ActiveDocument reference, and its Tables (plural) object reference, sounds reasonable that you are referencing all tables from the active document in the current application. Accessing page 5 must be done in a different way